# How to get specific rows, in a specific column to SUM?

Tags: sum

I am new to MS Query and programming all together.

I am trying to pull data from multiple tables. I need to have the `tot_cost_adj` column add the totals for the same `job_no`. This is what my table looks like now.

[My table now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KLmy.png)

This is the code I have in now

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT 
jobs.job_no, jobs.description, jobs.original_contract, job_chg.tot_cost_adj
FROM Cas_PW.dbo.job_chg job_chg, Cas_PW.dbo.jobs jobs
WHERE 
    job_chg.company_no = jobs.company_no 
    AND job_chg.job_no = jobs.job_no 
    AND ((jobs.original_contract>.00))
```

Any help to get the `tot_cost_adj` for the same job to have one total would be appreciated.

Thanks
Sari

Answer (score 0):

use `Group by` expression to group aggregate result by a column e,g jobno

```
so select jobs.job_no, sum(job_chg.tot_cost_adj) as total FROM Cas_PW.dbo.job_chg job_chg, Cas_PW.dbo.jobs jobs WHERE job_chg.company_no = jobs.company_no AND job_chg.job_no = jobs.job_no AND ((jobs.original_contract>.00))

group by jobs.job_no
```